# Unable to access server database with datagrip

Tags: datagrip

I've updated my datagrip to 2021.3.1 and now I'm having an issue where I can no longer access the database from a server.
in my SSH Configurations I filled it in with the correct Host, Port, User name. I've chosen the Key pair as my Authentication type.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to test the connection a popup comes and asks me to Log into the server but it asks for the password for
the id_rsa but I'm using a different ppk to access the database which is already specified in the SSH Configurations

Comment: Do you have something in system SSH config that should be read? Have you tried to recreate SSH configuration from scratch?

Comment: @YuriWin - Do you mean something like my private key?